# InvalidRequestError in SQLALchemy during commit

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

When saving the record in POST method, I am getting the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped class RegionalContact->regional_contact, expression 'RegionalContactType' failed to locate a name ('RegionalContactType'). 
If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'app.api.xyz.abc.models.regional_contact.RegionalContact'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

I have been checking [this SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many), but keep getting the above error. My configuration is as follows:

I have the following child tables:

```
class RegionalContactType(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'regional_contact_type'
    
    regional_contact_type_code = db.Column(db.String(3), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    
    
class RegionalCode(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'regional_code'
    
    region_code = db.Column(db.String(2), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
```

and the parent table with references to children tables:

```
class RegionalContact(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'regional_contact'
    
    regional_contact_type_code = db.Column(
        db.String(3),
        db.ForeignKey('regional_contact_type.regional_contact_type_code'),
        primary_key=True)
    region_code = db.Column(
        db.String(2), db.ForeignKey('regional_code.region_code'), primary_key=True)
    full_name = db.Column(db.String(100))

    region_code = db.relationship('RegionalCode', backref='regional_contact')
    contact_type = db.relationship('RegionalContactType', backref='regional_contact')
```

The class Base:

```
class Base(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True
    _edit_groups = []
    _edit_key = None
    query_class = UserBoundQuery
    _ModelSchema = SQLAlchemyAutoSchema

    def save(self, commit=True):
        db.session.add(self)
        if commit:
            try:
                db.session.commit()
            except SQLAlchemyError as e:
                db.session.rollback()
                raise e
```

However, when committing the record, getting the above error.

Do you know what is wrong with the configuration above?

Thanks :)

Comment: How are you making `Base` and importing it to your model files? Also, since you're using Flask-SQLAlchemy, why not use its `db.Model` as base?

Comment: Thanks @Ilja Everilä, I have included Base.

Comment: That looks ok. Next question: how have you organized importing your models? The error hints at the module with `RegionalContactType` not having been imported before you are trying to use `RegionalContact`, which means that the model class does not exist yet at that point.

Comment: Needed to import an additional model which was used as dependency.